# How to really, truly remove old kernels?

Tags: 16.04, apt, kernel, disk-usage, disk-management

I've read many answers on this site answering this question. I'm on 16.04, so the following should take care of old kernels:

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

Failing that, I can remove old ones manually (keeping recent kernels as backup):

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.*
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-extras-3.*
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.*
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.0.0-x*
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-extras-4.0.0-x*
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-4.0.0-x*
```

where I performed the last three commands for `x` = `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`. This did result in disk space being cleared, up to ~`500M` in some cases. However, I still see many MB of disk space being used on these old kernels in `/boot`:

```
ls -lh /boot

...

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14M Dec 17  2016 initrd.img-3.19.0-33-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14M Dec 17  2016 initrd.img-3.19.0-61-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14M Dec 17  2016 initrd.img-3.19.0-64-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14M Dec 17  2016 initrd.img-3.19.0-65-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14M Dec 17  2016 initrd.img-3.19.0-66-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14M Dec 17  2016 initrd.img-3.19.0-68-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14M Dec 17  2016 initrd.img-3.19.0-74-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14M Dec 17  2016 initrd.img-3.19.0-75-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14M Dec 17  2016 initrd.img-3.19.0-77-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39M Nov 28 09:41 initrd.img-4.4.0-101-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  15M Dec 17  2016 initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18M Aug 27 18:51 initrd.img-4.4.0-57-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18M Aug 27 18:51 initrd.img-4.4.0-59-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18M Aug 27 18:52 initrd.img-4.4.0-62-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18M Aug 27 18:52 initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18M Aug 27 18:53 initrd.img-4.4.0-71-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18M Aug 27 18:53 initrd.img-4.4.0-72-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18M Aug 27 18:53 initrd.img-4.4.0-75-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  18M Sep 23 11:33 initrd.img-4.4.0-78-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  39M Nov  4 17:00 initrd.img-4.4.0-98-generic  

...
```

and also, the old kernels are still listed as large installed packages by `dpkg`:

```
dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Installed-Size} ${Package}\n' | sort -nr | less

...

158659 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic
158555 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic
158443 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic
158201 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
157559 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic
157559 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic
156386 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-77-generic
156386 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-75-generic
156385 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-74-generic
156384 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-68-generic
156384 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-66-generic
156384 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-65-generic
156383 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-64-generic
156380 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-61-generic
156178 linux-image-extra-3.19.0-33-generic
150341 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic
150205 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic
150198 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic
149214 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic
149191 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic
149156 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic
148953 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic
148953 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-71-generic
148940 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic
148663 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-87-generic
148621 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-78-generic
148598 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-75-generic

...
```

How can I fully clean my system of these old kernels?

Answer (score 4):

You need to `purge` the kernels instead of just `remove`.

A handy tool is `purge-old-kernels` which is shipped with the `byobu` package on Ubuntu 16.04.

EDIT: on Ubuntu 18.04 and up you can use `apt autoremove` to remove old kernels as well.

Comment: Sorry, the HTH was my addition. I thought I was onto a bug, cause I am able to change the reply. Must be because I'm on a certain level? Otherwise, weird stuff..

Comment: BE CAREFUL!!! :  If your package manager tells you can remove lots of packages, check if it's kernel stuff ONLY.
You could make your install CORRUPT using the autoremove option. I've had this happen 2 times.
The behavior may start  after you remove a single program out of the desktop manager (gnome,mate?).
In this case, please remove the older kernels by HAND, using plain rm.  (also update the grub config file).
It must be, that the dependency tree of gnome?/mate? is not set up right.

Comment: `purge-old-kernels` *only* flags kernel-related packages to be removed. If your `apt` state is broken for any other reason, yes, you can remove more than you want using `apt`

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of all kernel-related packages with `apt list --installed | grep linux`, and `apt remove` those you don't want. It's that simple. You cab use `--purge` if you want, but it should not have any significant effect in that case.